# State is not updating in React after sorting?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to sort JSON object by date and number. Everything is working fine when i console log but the state is not getting updated on the GUI side. What am i missing? I am using the functional components.
Here is the code...

```
const Posts = () => {
  const [dummyData, setDummyData] = useState(Data);
  const sortList = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "date") {
      handleSort();
    } else if (e.target.value === "upvotes") {
      byUpvotes();
    }
  };
  const handleSort = () => {
    const sortedData = dummyData.sort((a, b) => {
      const c = new Date(a.published);
      const d = new Date(b.published);
      if (c.getDate() > d.getDate()) {
        return c;
      } else {
        return d;
      }
    });
    setDummyData(sortedData);
    console.log(sortedData);
  };

  const byUpvotes = () => {
    const sortByName = dummyData.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.upvotes - a.upvotes;
    });
    setDummyData(sortByName);
    console.log(sortByName);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {dummyData.map((post) => (
        <PostsItem key={post.id} post={post} />
      ))}

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-s6">
          <label>Browser Select</label>
          <select className="browser-default" onChange={sortList}>
            <option disabled selected>
              Choose your option
            </option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
            <option value="upvotes">Upvotes</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should look into `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sort function does not create a new array, it mutates the old one. So you're rearranging the existing state, and then setting state with the same array. Since it's the same array, react thinks the state hasn't changed and skips rendering.

Instead, you will need to make a copy of the array and then sort that. For example:

```
const byUpvotes = () => {
  const sortByName = [...dummyData];
  sortByName.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.upvotes - a.upvotes
  })
  setDummyData(sortByName)
}
```

Comment: thanks that's working now but the handlesort() method which is a sort by date is not sorting and updating the state although i added it into the empty array first still its not sorting correctly and showing in the state?

Comment: Your sort function needs to return a number. A positive number tells it to put `b` earlier in the array; a negative number puts `a` earlier in the array. Currently you're returning date objects (`c` and `d`)

Comment: I did return 1 and -1 still its not sorting. At least it should update my state but still no luck so far  I expored the other answers and they are sorting with the same method as i am doing.                                                                .                                                                            if (c.getDate() > d.getDate()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }

Comment: It would help if you show what the code looks like now with these changes. You can edit your original question (don't delete the old code, but you can add more info at the bottom)

Comment: Never mind i have solved the issue. Thankyou very much :)

Comment: Spent almost half of my day finding the issue.
This saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The state will only update when its reference is changed, here in your code state is sorted because the sort function only mutates the original array instead of creating a new array like a map, or filter that gives a new reference.
so, you should do like this

```
 const byUpvotes = () => {
        const sortByName = dummyData.sort((a, b) => {
          return b.upvotes - a.upvotes;
        }).map((num)=>num);
setDummyData(sortByName)};
```